# Qual a finalidade do "alt" em uma tag "<img />"?

Tags: html, html5

Estudando sobre *HTML5* me deparei com a propriedade `alt` sendo usada na tag `<img />`.

*Exemplo:*

```html
<img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/9e/fd/27/9efd27afef4e8127923fbce92b8c967d--minions-minions-funny-minion.jpg" alt='Essa é uma imagem sobre Minions' />
```

Gostaria  de saber qual a finalidade de `alt` em uma tag `<img />`, visto que, nada visual é apresentado.

Comment: Marconi, quebra o link e vera o que aparece no lugar ;)

Comment: Use 2 são `alt` e `title`, caso novos navegadores para mac, android e outros, quebrar link e se esta dizendo encurtar? entre http://goo.gl ou http://imgur.com

Comment: É mesmo pessoal bem melhor, valeu :)

Comment: Que bom se gostou encurtador, disponha ;-)

Comment: Aqui tem um exemplo Marconi: https://jsfiddle.net/jmo802c9/

Comment: @Miguel vdd aqui msm na empresa acontece isso cmg, não sabia que era por causa do alt que aparecia esse texto, achei que fosse o tooltip.

Comment: Sim, até mesmo quando a conecção está lenta consegue no Facebook ver a descrição (alt) das imagens antes de elas aparecerem mesmo

Comment: @Miguel entendi, Obrigado pelo link :)

Comment: tooltip tem jquery ui e segue https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/ é bonito!

Comment: `alt` é alternativo, o foco principal é servir de fallback para acaso a imagem não carregue, todavia os buscadores usam para descrever o conteudo, semelhante ao `title`. Portanto não precisa de `title` dentro de  `img`, basta usar `alt=`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento boa, cada hora aprendendo um pouco mais.

Comment: Dá pra fazer uma resposta só com uns bons comentarios que tem aqui. :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

É para colocar a descrição do que a imagem contém. Ela será mostrada no lugar da imagem se ela não puder ser exibida. Útil para:

- facilitar a indexação do conteúdo, então serve para SEO,
- mostrar alguma coisa informativa se o navegador não carregar a imagem por algum motivo ou estiver lento,
- poder informar alguma coisa para quem tem deficiência visual.

O último é importante porque os softwares de leituras para quem tem dificuldade visual pode ler o que está escrito e "falar" para a pessoa. Não tem como (ainda) "contar" para a pessoa o que é a imagem, só dá para fazer isso com uma descrição.

Muita gente acha que tudo sempre funcionará, mas tem várias razões para a imagem não ser exibida:

- tem navegador que não pode mostrar a imagem, ele é textual,
- o navegador pode ser configurado para não mostrar imagens,
- tem rede que pode ter bloqueio do local onde tem a imagem,
- a imagem pode deixar de existir onde estava e você não perceber,
- pode haver diversos erros no meio do processo.

Não use o espaço para colocar o nome da imagem ou algo pouco útil. O texto deve descrever a imagem o melhor possível para atender esses requisitos ditos acima. Se for necessário pode colocar um texto longo, mas nem sempre isso é necessário, não é preciso fazer uma crítica artística da imagem :). Se houver conflito entre os objetivos, faça o melhor possível para atender o mais importante e tente ajudar nos demais.

Não precisa usar se a imagem for meramente decorativa, use `<alt = "">` nesses casos, só imagens importantes para o contexto geral da página é que precisam disso. Não deixe de usar essa forma para que o navegador não mostre algo, para que não tente descrever que tem uma imagem ali, que na verdade só seria útil para a página *renderizada* por completo.

O exemplo adequado é o que está na pergunta mesmo :) não tem muito segredo.

[Documentação na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img).

Aqui no site permite fazer isso quando adiciona imagem e poucos o fazem, isso é ruim e pouco inclusivo.

Exemplo:

[image: Meme com um Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas e frase "funcionar é diferente de star certo"]

Se o navegador não mostra *tooltip* veja o fonte deste texto com a descrição dela.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 8):

Na minha opinião, a grande importância do `alt` é na acessibilidade, inclusive a [W3C](http://www.w3c.br/Home/WebHome) (*World Wide Web Consortium*) possui esse [slide](http://www.w3c.br/pub/Agenda/PalestraAcessibilidadeEHtml5/FrontInBH-ago2011.pdf) sobre acessibilidade na web.

Existem alguns leitores de tela como o ORCA, para Linux e JAMS para Windows, nesse [site](http://www.oampliadordeideias.com.br/ideia.php?id=4) tem uma explicação sobre eles. Com a tag `alt` esses softwares informam para os usuários deficientes o que está na imagem. É por isso, que a função principal da tag é fornecer uma descrição alternativa para a imagem.

Caso tenha interesse em saber mais sobre acessibilidade na web, recomendo a leitura da [cartilha](http://www.w3c.br/pub/Materiais/PublicacoesW3C/cartilha-w3cbr-acessibilidade-web-fasciculo-I.html) da W3C.

Lembre-se que pequenos detalhes, como `<img src="https://goo.gl/3pS3AU" alt='Essa é uma imagem sobre Minions' />`, no seu HTML fazem grande diferença para usuários deficientes.

Comment: Concordo com você.

Comment: Vou dedicar um tempo nesse PDF em. :)

Comment: @Marconi, vale a pena =)