# O que é o CSS Aural?

Tags: css

O CSS que conheçemos formata a informação entregue pelo HTML. Essa informação pode ser qualquer coisa por exemplo: *imagem, texto, vídeo, áudio* ou qualquer outro elemento criado, ou seja, o  CSS formata a informação.

Encontrei o termo ***CSS AURAL*** que combina síntese de voz e efeitos sonoros, e não informação.

Gostaria de entender um pouco mais sobre, então tenho dúvidas nos seguintes aspectos:

1. Posso dizer que é um novo Framework criado a parti do CSS?
2. Como o termo é novo(para mim), poderia explicar onde é usado e sua finalidade?
3. Existe algum publico(usuário final) em especial a que se destina?

PS: Se possível dê exemplos de uso:)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### O CSS que fala.

Apesar [de obsoleta](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/aural.html), folhas de estilo Aural tem como objetivo uma combinação de síntese de fala e efeitos sonoros para que o usuário possa ouvir a informação, em vez de lê-la.

> [...]onde é usado e sua finalidade? Existe algum publico(usuário final) em especial a que se destina?

Ajudam usuários com restrições visuais.

Exemplo:

```
h1, h2 {
    voice-family: male;
    richness: 80;
    cue-before: url("som.wav")
}
```

O exemplo acima fará com que o sintetizador de voz reproduza os cabeçalhos em uma voz grave masculina usando `voice-family` como `male`.

Veja mais detalhes [em W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/aural.html)<sup>(en)</sup>.

PS.: No site do Acessibilidade Inclusiva tem [uma postagem](http://www.acessibilidadeinclusiva.com.br/programas-para-computadores/) que faz uma listagem de alguns softwares para deficientes visuais, se você tem interesse, vale apena dar uma lida a respeito. Obs.: Não sei quais tecnoligias são usadas por cada uma para desenvolvimento desses softwares. Quiz inserir aqui apenas para complementação.

Comment: @Marconi não entendi também, mas vai saber.

Comment: Não gosto de respostas negativas sem um comentário a indicar porque, volta lá para o neutro!

Comment: Boa tarde, marquei com -1 porque estava usando como **Documentação** a W3Schools. Você mudou para uma fonte que se autodenomina obsoleta.

Comment: @Marconi de acordo com essa referência do W3 sim, o CSS Aural está obsoleto. Na própria página deles tem uma nota alertando as pessoas.

Comment: @Marconi estou até procurando se há algum substituto para isso para poder te ajudar, porque sinceramente, na prática nunca vi ninguém usando.

Comment: @Marconi eu acho muito importante as pessoas importarem com isso, porque a acessibilidade, não só no Brasil, como no mundo todo, é muito ruim. Estava lendo aqui que o Facebook criou uma ferramente para os deficientes visuais "verem" as imagens. Não sei como, talvez alguma forma de descrever, claro, em formato de áudio.

Comment: @AckLay Falando em ver as imagens, veja essa  [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/164876/qual-a-finalidade-de-alt-em-uma-tag-img) que fiz recentemente sobre o uso do `alt` em tags `imgs` respondida pelo bigown. Pode ser relacionado com o seu comentario!

Comment: @Marconi legal, aqui a matéria. http://www.techtudo.com.br/noticias/noticia/2015/10/facebook-desenvolve-ferramenta-para-ajudar-cegos-ver-imagens.html Eu leve muito a sério a questão de acessibilidade.

Answer (score 7):

**CSS Aural - Estilos destinados à Acessibilidade Visual**

É comumente usado por pessoas cegas, com dificuldade de visão ou que não possuem um ecrã para visualização. É utilizado, por exemplo, por [*Screen Readers*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leitor_de_tela), que é todo software que traduz de forma sonara (e sintetizada) o conteúdo, ao invés de exibi-lo.

Não é um FRAMEWORK, mas sim um MÓDULO do CSS, projetado para a acessibilidade.

Acredito que isso já responda todos os aspectos da pergunta e quanto à exemplos, segue:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
{
  voice-family: paul;
  voice-stress: moderate;
  cue-before: url(../audio/ping.wav);
  voice-volume: medium 6dB;
}
p.heidi
{
  voice-family: female;
  voice-balance: left;
  voice-pitch: high;
  voice-volume: -6dB;
}
p.peter
{
  voice-family: male;
  voice-balance: right;
  voice-rate: fast;
}
span.special
{
  voice-volume: soft;
  pause-after: strong;
}

...

<h1>I am Paul, and I speak headings.</h1>
<p class="heidi">Hello, I am Heidi.</p>
<p class="peter">
  <span class="special">Can you hear me ?</span>
  I am Peter.
</p>
```

A navegação em um site, feita sem auxílio visual, é feita através de saltos de elemento para elemento, assim o CSS Aural permiti estilizar como será lido para o usuário o elemento em foco, mudando entre masculino/feminino, definindo o volume e etc.

Apenas complementando o Aspecto de *Testes/Screen Readers* o [DOSVOX](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dosvox) é uma iniciativa Brasileira e Open Source.

Documentação da W3 acerca de CSS Aural e Speech: [FONTE](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-speech-1/)