# Posso usar acentuação e outros caracteres no atributo alt?

Tags: html5

Eu posso deixar o atributo `alt` com cedilha e acentuado? Por exemplo: `<alt="Açaí">`. Afinal, para que serve o atributo alt?

Comment: Veja: [**Qual a finalidade de alt em uma tag <img />?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/164876/)

Comment: Essa pegunta poderia ser respondida testando facilmente, não existe a necessidade da pergunta