# Duvida sobre HTML em relaçao ao comando alt=" "

Tags: html

É o seguinte, minha imagem nao esta aparecendo o texto que coloquei no alt=" " quando coloco o mouse em cima.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>teste</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="foto.jpg" alt="foto" />
</body>
</html>
```

Tem algo de errado no script?
Eu tenho um site hospedado no 000webhost, e nele também não esta aparedendo o que eu escrevi no alt=" ".

Comment: Dá uma olhada: [Qual a finalidade de alt em uma tag <img />?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/164876/qual-a-finalidade-de-alt-em-uma-tag-img)

Comment: Tem que colocar o atributo **title** para mostrar algum texto.

Comment: Pesquise a diferença entre `alt` e `title`.

Comment: Como já dito, o que você quer é o atributo `title`, mas não deixe de usar o `alt` por questão de acessibilidade

Comment: Entendi, obrigado!

Comment: @LINQ não vejo como as respostas ai poderiam resolver o problema, quero dizer é um otimo adendo e explica o que é, mas não vai resolver, eu entendo que o titulo da pergunta esta péssimo e faz entender ao contrário, mas o corpo da pergunta deixa mais claro a necessidade. Acho que dá para alguém formular uma resposta simples e apontar este link da pergunta como um adendo.

Answer (score 1):

O atributo `alt=""` em imagens não serve para exibir o tooltip desejado, o objetivo deste atributo é explicado melhor em:

- [Qual a finalidade de alt em uma tag <img />?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164876/3635)

O que você quer é exibir o tooltip.

Vale notar que talvez alguns navegadores como **IE6 exibiam o tal tooltip quando usado o atributo `alt=`**, mas não quer dizer que era certo.

Então para exibir o tal tooltipo o atributo "global" a ser usado é o `title=""`, claro que vale notar que ele tem comportamento variado as vezes, como em elementos `<link ...>`:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-title

Então deveria ficar assim:

```html
<img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/br/img/sprites.svg?v=9a80d5fa584d" alt="sprites do stack overflow" title="sprites do stack overflow" />
```

Note que apesar de ter colocado o texto em `alt` e em `title` de maneiras iguais, ambos tem objetivos diferentes, apesar de ambos serem usados eventualmente em SEO para descrição, o comportamento em leitores de tela é variante, apesar de ser mais interessante dar uma olhada sobre os atributos `aria`:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/

Mas leitores de tela vai um pouco além da pergunta, deixo o link só acaso tenha interesse em se aprofundar no assunto.

Answer (score -1):

Alt é um texto alternativo que aparece se não for possível carregar a imagem

```html
<img src="naocarrega.png" alt= "Imagem nao carregada">
<img src="https://www.google.com.br/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="Este texto nao aparece" width="110" height="50"/>
```